# What is the def paradox_stats() function in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn how to write a function that could test the probability of same birthday of two people in a room.

> The birthday paradox says that the probability that two people in a room will have the same birthday is more than half, provided n, the number of people in the room, is more than 23. This property is not really a paradox, but many people find it surprising. Design a Python program that can test this paradox by a series of experiments on randomly generated birthdays, which test this paradox for n = 5,10,15,20,... ,100.

Here is the code that showed in my book.

```
import random
def test_birthday_paradox(num_people):
    birthdays = [random.randrange(0,365) for _ in range(num_people)]
    birthday_set = set()
    for bday in birthdays:
        if bday in birthday_set: return True
        else: birthday_set.add(bday)
    return False


def paradox_stats(num_people = 23, num_trials = 100):
    num_successes = 0
    for _ in range(num_trials):
        if test_birthday_paradox(num_people): num_successes += 1
    return num_successes/num_trials

paradox_stats(31)
0.77
```

I can't understand the code from `def paradox_stats` to the end of code.
Can someone help me , please?

Comment: what part is unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing that `paradox_state(31)` is a mistake and you want to write `paradox_stats(31)`:

`def paradox_stats(num_people = 23, num_trials = 100):` is the definition of the function where two variables could be inserted (these variables are optional).

`num_successes = 0` the code are initializing the variable `num_successes` to zero.

```py
for _ in range(num_trials):
        if test_birthday_paradox(num_people): num_successes += 1
return num_successes/num_trials
```

Here the code is running throw a range from 0 to the number of trials which the user could define once is calling the function (remember it is an optional variable).

In this loop the code is using the previous function `test_birthday_paradox` (which I suppose you understand as far as you say in your question) to know if someone in the room has the same birthday. In the case that the function returns True (someone has the same birthday) the variable `num_successes` increase its value in one (this is how works `+=` syntax, but if you need further explanation `num_successes+=1 == num_successes = num_successes+1`).

And once the loop is completed the function `paradox_stats` return the probability in the random sample as the number of successes vs number of trials.

Hope my answer can help you.